# Bigquery full date (year-month-day) to (year-month)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

a noob question.

I want to query my database looking for pageviews for a given page, and i wrote a query that returns the page / number of pageviews daily. How i should change my query to get the same statistics but not daily but mothly?

So instead:

```
page      pv   date
/mysite   10   2017-01-01
```

get

```
page      pv   date
/mysite   500  2017-01
```

my query:

```
select
date, 
hits.page.pagePath as pagePath, 
count(totals.pageviews) as pageViews
from Table_DATE_RANGE ([818251235.ga_sessions_] , Timestamp('2016-01-01'), Timestamp('2017-11-01'))
group by 1,2
```

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to count in your original query, but here is a query that uses standard SQL and performs the grouping on a monthly basis:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date), MONTH) AS month,
  hit.page.pagePath,
  ‎COUNT(*)
FROM `818251235.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST (hits) AS hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN
    '20160101' AND '20181101'
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Edit: fixed to use `DATE_TRUNC` instead of `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ...)` since both the year and month are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can use date functions like `UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH`, `UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK`, `UTC_USEC_TO_DAY` to normalize them to the first day of the month, first day of the week.

```
select 
date(UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(date)) as monthly, 
.....
```